# Android, drawable, layout, button

Tags: android

Я создал файл в `drawable` с названием `button1.xml` и содержанием:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/gray"/>
<item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/white"/>
</selector>
```

При попытке присвоить `background`, через `android:background="@drawable/button1"`, выдает ошибку:

> Element type "Button" must be followed by either attribute
>   specifications, ">" or "/>".

Что я делаю не так?

Вот код `Layout` файла:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Выберите словарь"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.75"
        android:background="@color/gray" >      
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:layout_margin="2sp" >

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/lv1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                </ListView>
            </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/gray" >

       <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button1"
            android:text="@string/add"
            android:layout_margin="3sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

внимательно читайте свой код!

```html
android:background="@drawable/button1""
```

уберите в конце лишнюю кавычку и вам будет счастье:

```
android:background="@drawable/button1"
```

Comment: Ой... Убрал, помогло. Но вторая ошибка так и осталась. P.S. Я отредактировал код в вопросе, чтобы не путать людей.

Comment: а какой второй вопрос?Ошибка "Element type "Button" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"" в том и заключалась, что из-за неправильного синтаксиса не был виден конец элемента

Comment: Ошибка "Element type "Button" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"." осталась, к сожалению :c.

Comment: попробуйте взять код, который у вас в вопросе, вставить в разметку и сохранить файл

Comment: и вначале поставьте <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Comment: Это что за магия?) Сработало! Кстати, работает и без "`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`".

Comment: Теперь не работает файл button1, но это уже другая песня :).